# How to append dictionary to a list in loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have at my disposal huge amount of data, in the form of a list of tuples. Each tuple has a specified format like `(a, b, c, d, e)`. The list of tuples looks like:

```
tupleList = [('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'),
             ('a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'),
             ...
             ('a10000', 'b10000', 'c10000', 'd10000', 'e100000')]
```

What I want is, to convert each of these tuples to a dictionary, and append the dictionary to a a final list of dictionaries. Can all this be done in a loop? The final list of dictionaries should look like:

```
finalDictList = [{'key1': 'a1', 'key2': 'b1', 'key3': 'c1', 'key4': 'd1', 'key5': 'e1'},
                 {'key1': 'a2', 'key2': 'b2', 'key3': 'c2', 'key4': 'd2', 'key5': 'e2'},
                 {'key1': 'a3', 'key2': 'b3', 'key3': 'c3', 'key4': 'd3', 'key5': 'e3'},
                 ...
                 {'key1': 'a10000', 'key2': 'b10000', 'key3': 'c10000', 'key4': 'd10000', 'key5': 'e10000'}]
```

The format of the tuples is fixed. I want to compare afterwords, value of each key of a dictionary with all others. This is why the conversion of tuple to dictionary made sense to me. Please correct me if the design paradigm itself seems wrong. Also, there are >10000 tuples. Declaring that many dictionaries is just not done.

Is there anyway to append dictionary to a list in a loop? Also, if that is possible, can we access each dictionary by it's key values, say, like `finalDictList[0]['key1']`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We're going to mix three important concepts to make this code really small and beautiful. First, a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), then, the [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) method, and finally, the [dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) method, to build a dictionary out of a list of tuples:

```
my_list = [('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2')]
keys = ('key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5')
final = [dict(zip(keys, elems)) for elems in my_list]
```

After that, the value of the `final` variable is:

```
>>> final
[{'key3': 'c1', 'key2': 'b1', 'key1': 'a1', 'key5': 'e1', 'key4': 'd1'},
{'key3': 'c2', 'key2': 'b2', 'key1': 'a2', 'key5': 'e2', 'key4': 'd2'}]
```

Also, you can get elements of a certain dictionary using the position of the dictionary in the list and the key you're looking for, i.e.:

```
>>> final[0]['key1']
'a1'
```

Comment: @sneha: glad I helped, if this post solved your problem, you could choose it as accepted (green check on the left)

Answer (score 6):

Use `zip` to combine a pre-defined list of key names with each tuple in your input list, then pass the results to `dict` to make them into dicts. Wrap the whole thing in a list comprehension to process them all in one batch:

```
keys = ('key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5')
finalDictList = [dict(zip(keys, values)) for values in tupleList]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I see why you need to convert everything to a dictionary, when you've already got a list of tuples.

```
>>> tupleList = [('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'),
...              ('a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'),
...              ('a10000', 'b10000', 'c10000', 'd10000', 'e100000')]
>>> [x[1] for x in tupleList]
['b1', 'b2', 'b10000']
```

Using Python's *list comprehension* syntax, you can get a list of all the n-th elements of each tuple.

Comment: I know of this, but the entries in the tuple are related to each other - that is, (a,b,c,d,e) are values that make sense together only. I understand that for comparing this is fine, but i have to work on the complete tuple in case during comparison a match occurs/doesn't occur. I can make this work, but it'll be in a round about way. Thank you! :)

Comment: @sneha: Accessing elements of a tuple is almost exactly the same syntax as accessing elements of a dictionary: `x[2]` vs `x["key2"]`. If you want, you can define constants like `KEY2 = 2`, so you can do `x[KEY2]`. Converting to a list of dictionaries will take up a lot more memory for little benefit.

Comment: Hmmm...I guess you have a pretty good point there. Let me reconsider my design. :)

Answer (score 3):

If the fields are fix you can do this:

```
fields = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5']

newList = [dict(zip(fields, vals)) for vals in oldList]
```

Answer (score 2):

If as you say you have a lot of entries, remember that python has [namedtuples](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields):

```
>>> tupleList = [('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'),
...              ('a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'),
...              ('a10000', 'b10000', 'c10000', 'd10000', 'e100000')]
>>>
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> fv = namedtuple('fivevals', ('key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5'))
>>> tuplelist = [fv(*item) for item in tupleList]
>>> 
>>> tuplelist[0].key1
'a1'
>>>
```

Namedtuples can be accesed by key but at the same time they are lightweight and require no more memory than regular tuples.

Comment: Ack! I'm ashamed that I didn't remember that. Good call!

Answer (score 0):

```
finalDictList = []
for t in tupleList:
    finalDictList.append({
        'key1': t[0],
        'key2': t[1],
        'key3': t[2],
        'key4': t[3],
        'key5': t[4],
    })
```

> Also, if that is possible, can we access each dictionary by it's key values, say, like finalDictList[0]['key1']?

Absolutely, that is exactly how you would do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip

keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5']
finalDictList = [dict(izip(names, x)) for x in tupleList]
```

Comment: To avoid building a temporary list in each iteration of course.

Comment: That seems like you'd be trading a tiny memory allocation for the overhead of a generator.