# Take 2 key values from list of python dicts & make new list/tuple/array/dictionary with each index containing 2 key values from 1st listed dict

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of dictionaries in a json file.

I have iterated through the list and each dictionary to obtain two specific key:value pairs from each dictionary for each element.
     i.e. `List[dictionary{i(key_x:value_x, key_y:value_y)}]`

My question is now:

How do I place these two new key: value pairs in a new list/dictionary/array/tuple, representing the two key: value pairs extracted for each listed element in the original?

To be clear:

```
ORIGINAL_LIST      (i.e. with each element being a nested dictionary) = 
[{"a":{"blah":"blah",
      "key_1":value_a1,
      "key_2":value_a2,
      "key_3":value_a3,
      "key_4":value_a4,
      "key_5":value_a5,},
  "b":"something_a"},
 {"a":{"blah":"blah",
      "key_1":value_b1,
      "key_2":value_b2,
      "key_3":value_b3,
      "key_4":value_b4,
      "key_5":value_b5,},
  "b":"something_b"}]
```

So my code so far is:

```py
    import json
    from collections import *
    from pprint import pprint

    json_file = "/some/path/to/json/file"

    with open(json_file) as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()

    for i in data:
        event = dict(i)
        event_key_b = event.get('b')
        event_key_2 = event.get('key_2')
        print(event_key_b)#print value of "b" for each nested dict for 'i'
        print(event_key_2)#print value of "key_2" for each nested dict for 'i'
```

To be clear:

```
FINAL_LIST(i.e. with each element being a nested dictionary) = 

    [{"b":"something_a", "key_2":value_2},
     {"b":"something_b", "key_2":value_2}]
```

Comment: Can you clarify your `FINAL_LIST`, why are only `key_2` present?

Comment: some reason stack cut out the second part of the dictionary, it should have another nested dictionary with {"b":"something_b", {"key_2":value_2}}]

Comment: final list should be:

[{"b":"something_a", {"key_2":value_2}},
 {"b":"something_b", {"key_2":value_2}}]

Comment: Add it to the question

Comment: I think I understand your confusion, the nested dictionary I used for the final list didn't make sense, I have edited it in the question to reflect this, thanks

Comment: I found this question and solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947327/how-to-append-dictionary-to-a-list-in-loop
 but to be honest not quite sure how to implement list comprehension and zip in my case

Answer (score 0):

So I have an answer to getting the keys into individual dictionaries, as follows in the code below. The only problem is that the value for 'key_2' in the original json dictionaries is either an int value or it is "" for values which are 0. My script just returns 'None' for all instances of value_2 for key_2. How can I get it to read the appropriate values for 'value_2'? I want to only return dictionaries for cases where 'value_2' > 0 (i.e. where value_2 != "")

Below is the current code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_file = "/some/path/to/json/file"

with open(json_file) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()

for i in data:
    event_key_b = event.get('b')
    for x in i:
        event_key_2 = event.get('key_2')
        x = {'b' : something_b, 'key_2' : value_2}
    print(x)
```

Also, if there are any more elegant solutions anyone can think of I would really be interested in learning them ... Some of the json files I'm looking at can range from 200 dictionary entries in the original list to 2,000,000. I'm planning to feed my parsed results into a message queue for processing by a different service and any efficiencies in the code will help for scalability in processing. Also if anyone has any recommendations to give on Redis vs. RabbitMQ, I'd really appreciate it